# Moving a standalone 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, migration

I've inherited maintenance of an existing SharePoint standalone instance, and I have now to move it to a new server; I've up to now tried a few things, spent a day searching on the web, but still no luck. Note that I've never used SharePoint before.

So, there is an old server with SharePoint 2013 installed in standalone instance and a small internal website hosted on it (just a bunch of pages and attached files), and there is a new server with the same SharePoint version installed: I need to migrate existing stuff to the new server, and have no idea of how to do it.

I already tried to backup the old db with the Central Administration tool, got as a result a folder full of of .bak files, moved the .bak files to the new server, launched a restore, and the CA tool says there is no history backup in the folder.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the destination server having the same version number or above then i would move this way.

- take the content Database backup from the SQL server
- Move the Backup to new Server
- Restore the Backup to new SQL server
- Attach the Database to desired webapp.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but...a bit more detailed? Apart from knowing how to use SQL Server, there are 12 DB on the source server (which one is the content DB?) and I have no idea of how to "Attach the Database to desidered webapp"